# silverlight 4 unit testing

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

I have created Silverlight 4 unit test application. I am wondering that is there any way to call database from Silverlight 4 application to perform some test methods.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should be testing the silverlight-specific stuff (view models, etc) instead of testing directly against the db. In order to test only the silverlight stuff, you can mock a domain client and inject it into the Ria service context constructors. Here's an example:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-8-Testing-and-Debugging.aspx